# Can an imaginary pair of straight lines passing through origin have real straight lines as their angle bisectors?

Tags: geometry

I came across the following question:

> Find the equation of the bisectors of the angle between the lines represented by $$3x^2-5xy+4y^2=0$$

In the solution, they directly used the formula of combined equation of angle bisectors for a pair of straight lines passing through origin, i.e. $$h(x^2-y^2)-(a-b)xy=0 \tag{$\star$}$$
where the given lines have equation $a x^2 + 2 h x y + b y^2 = 0$.

And after using this formula we get $5x^2-2xy-5y^2=0$ as the combined equation of angle bisectors for a pair of straight lines represented by
$3x^2-5xy+4y^2=0$.

Now, two questions:

> 1. How is it possible that angle bisectors of two imaginary lines are real lines?
> 2. For a pair of real lines passing through the origin, how is formula $(\star)$ derived?

Please guide me through this confusion.

Comment: See [this entry on Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/coordinate-geometry-angle-bisector/) for a derivation of the formula.

Comment: Read the classic book
"The Methods of Plane Projective Geometry Based on the Use of General Homogeneous Coordinates" by
Maxwell, E.A to answer this sort of question.

Comment: Angle bisectors of imaginary lines make some sort of sense if you view them as the principal axes of a conic, in this case a degenerate one. The associated matrix to this conic is real symmetric, so has a complete set of orthogonal eigenvectors, which point in the directions of the principal axes.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get at the formula is to suppose that one angle bisector is inclined at some angle $\theta$ (so that the other bisector is at angle $\theta+\pi/2$), and that the two given lines are inclined by $\pm \phi$ relative to that bisector.

Then the combined equation of the lines is given by
$$\left(y - x\tan(\theta+\phi)\right)\left(y-x\tan(\theta-\phi)\right) = 0 \quad\to\quad a x^2 + b y^2 + 2 h x y = 0 \tag{1}$$
where 
$$a = \sin(\theta+\phi)\sin(\theta-\phi) \qquad b = \cos(\theta+\phi)\cos(\theta-\phi) \qquad h = - \sin\theta\cos\theta \tag{2}$$

And the combined equation of the bisectors is given by
$$(y-x\tan\theta)(y-\tan(\theta+\pi/2))=0 \quad\to\quad p (x^2-y^2) + q x y = 0 \tag{3}$$
where
$$\begin{align}
p &= \phantom{-}\sin\theta \cos\theta &&= -h \\
q &= -\cos 2\theta &&=\phantom{-}a-b
\end{align} \tag{4}$$
Dividing $(3)$ by $-1$ gives equation $(\star)$ in the question. $\square$